# Symfony DOMPDF and namespaces

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces, dompdf

I'm trying to use the DOMPDF library with the Symfony framework. I put the necessary file to include in autoload.php.
When I try to use it inside an action in a controller I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'MyProject\ClientBundle\Controller\DOMPDF' not found in /var/www.....

I uses namespaces, this is my first line in my controller file:

```
namespace MyProject\ClientBundle\Controller;
```

The DOMPDF library doesn't use namespaces.
How could I make it work?

Comment: you can also use: https://github.com/SlikNL/DompdfBundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using namespaces and your library doesn't, that means that DOMPDF is avaliable in the global namespace environment. When you call some class from a some namespace, PHP uses relative namespace path by default. If you want to get access to the global namespace you should add a backslash at the start of the class namespace you are calling, e.g. `use \DOMPDF`. That means you are using absolute path to a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put a backslash in front of the classname.